# brew install gcc46 fails with Clang/xcrun error

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, homebrew

I'm trying to use RVM to install ruby 1.9.2 and 1.9.3. It fails because one of the dependencies seems to be gcc46, and rvm uses brew to install it.

```
rbanerjee:~ $ sudo brew install gcc46
==> Installing dependencies for gcc46: gmp4, mpfr2, libmpc08, ppl011, cloog-ppl015
==> Installing gcc46 dependency: gmp4
==> Downloading ftp://ftp.gmplib.org/pub/gmp-4.3.2/gmp-4.3.2.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gmp4-4.3.2.tar.bz2
==> Patching
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gmp4/4.3.2 --enable-cxx --build=x86_64-apple-darwin
checking ABI=64
checking compiler clang  ... no
checking ABI=32
checking compiler clang  ... no
configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details
```

but clang is there and working:

```
rbanerjee:~ $ which clang
/usr/bin/clang
rbanerjee:~ $ clang -v
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix
```

Weird that the version is 4.2, since I have Xcode 4.6.3 and command line tools 4.6.3 installed. xcrun seems to be a problem too. Digging through the gcc46 logs leads to a failure to install gmp4:
in ~/Library/Logs/Homebrew/gmp4/config.log

```
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/clang:338:in `exec': No such file or directory - xcrun (Errno::ENOENT)
        from /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/clang:338
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance. OSX Lion. Here's all my system info:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9e2cdb6c0d0ca0b29eba

Comment: I did look in config.log. By timestamps it looks like i was adding more info while you were quick to find my error. see that bit about xcrun that's there. That's the nested error.

Comment: This looks tricky. Opening an issue at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues with the link returned by `brew gist-logs --config --doctor gmp4` will get the right eyes on it.